# He might come but,

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of the following sentence

> He might come, but I should be surprised.

Is there a clause of condition involved?

Comment: Can you tell us where this sentence came from? It's generally **not** a good practice to ask what something means yet leave the origin of the quote a complete mystery. See [*Why you should cite your source*](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) on meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an implied condition: "He might come but **if he did come** I should be surprised".

Note that "should" here is nothing to do with obligation: it is a slightly old-fashioned form used instead of "would" for the first person. Most people would way "I would be surprised" (or "I'd be surprised").

Also note, that "I'd be surprised" is effectively an idiom. It can be used with an explicit condition, but it is often used without one.